# how to use my public IP with HttpListener

Tags: c#, .net, httplistener

I've got this so far...

```
public static HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
public static string startUpPath = Application.StartupPath;
public  WebServer()
{
    listener.Start();

    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://(here I want my public ip)/");
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clientListener));
    t.Start();
}
```

But when I initialize the class it says `"The specified Network format is not valid"`

The translation may not be perfect because my visual studio language is in Spanish.
My ip looks like 95.^^.^^^.^^ and I think that may be the problem because it works when I use my local ip.

//Edited

The exact exception is:
"El formato del nombre de red especificado no es válido"
Which is`"The specified network name is not valid".`
If I add the prefix 
`"http:// + :80/"` 
it still going, but how can I access that through my public ip?

Comment: What's the exact exception?

Comment: What happens if you add the prefix `http://+:80/`?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here, do you want to know how to retrieve the public ip or is there a problem when it's used?

Comment: The problem is when he uses his public ip as follows, listener.Prefixes.Add("http://95.123.456.789/"); he receives the error.  It also sounds as if he does not receive the error if he uses his development ip or explicitly states the port number.

Comment: Yeah , exactly that :'(

Answer (score 6):

When setting this up you should use your internal IP, since that is the actual IP you are listening on.
In-order to get traffic from the your external IP, you need to forward that traffic from your router to your computer that is listening on its internal IP.

One way to set it up is to use port forwarding, from your router, you would want to direct any traffic that comes in on port 80 to your computer.

More info:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Comment: Actually it looks to be my router's problem because it doesn't forward ports, thanks for your time and your answer  , your link is pretty interesting and I will read it Jamie.

Answer (score 1):

As Jamie said, your HTTPListener should be bound to the IP address on the network card where the application is running.  Unless you have a NIC that is actually configured with a public IP (e.g. not going through a router) then your private address is the one to use.

An easy way to check this is to run IPCONFIG and see what IP address is listed.